# Angular switch between scss files

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a project in Angular 9.

In it, I have 2 themes in my application. One light and one dark.

I'm importing them into the style.scss file like this:

```
@import '../assets/lighttheme.scss';
@import '../assets/darktheme.scss';
```

My question is, how can I switch between these themes in my app.component.ts?

Comment: there are tons of tutorials out there on how to do this.
Here is one:
https://coryrylan.com/blog/theming-angular-apps-with-css-custom-properties

Comment: Your example is different to what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to toggle imported scss filesfrom app.component.ts where the imports are in the style.scss file. I'm not looking to toggle classes but actual scss files when the app loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this reference [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-material-theming?file=theme.scss) if you are using angular material in your application.

Thanks @BunyaminCoskuner for feedback. Here is my alternate solution which is from [Angular material Guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming):
if you want to completely swap a theme without including angular material custom theme approach then you can swap the loaded theme file by adding id attribute to your css link like :

```
<link id="darkTheme" rel="stylesheet" href="/path/dark-theme.csss">
```

Add below lines in your component:

```
changeTheme(themeName){document.getElementById('darkTheme').href='path/${themeName}.css';}
```